# Android files in intenal storage and local directory

Tags: android

Android gives you getDir (I assume this means I would have myappspace/somedirectory) to create a directory in you application space.  But how do you read or write to a file in that directory when android gives you an error if you have the path separator in the openFileOutput/Input call it gives you an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getDir returns a File object. To manipulate the directory and file structure, you continue to use File objects. For example

```
File dir = getDir("myDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File myFile = new File(dir, "myFile");
```

the openFileOutput simply returns a FileOutputStream based on some text criteria. All we have to do is create the object

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

From here, you continue as normal.

```
String hello = "hello world";
out.write(hello.getBytes());
out.close();
```

FileInputStream would follow the same guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` work with files in that directory  directly so they don't need an absolute pathname.

EDIT: More accurately, they work with files in the directory returned by `getFilesDir()` rather than `getDir()` which is normally the package root.

If you want to create custom directories relative to `getDir()`, then you'll need to use classes/methods other than `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` (such as using *InputStream* and *OutputStream* and relevant file 'reader' / 'writer' classes).

Comment: Huh, so if I have in my app space x.txt and dummy/x.txt android will do what then?

Comment: @arinte: What do you mean by 'app space'?

Comment: application local storage, but you have pretty much answered my question.  This is a hole in the API in my opinion.  Why have the convenience method to create a directory, but not support it in the other convenience methods.

Comment: @arinte: I think, in general, it isn't assumed that 'formal' directory structures are necessary and pretty much most 'working' files can just be located in the app's '/files' directory. This keeps them together in a private storage space which will be cleaned up if the app is un-installed. I think it works for most people but if you want a more complex structure you need to expect to use more complex approach. I can see +/- sides to it but it's basically what we've got to work with.

Comment: @MisterSquonk getDir() doesn't return the app's /files directory for me, actually, at least not with MODE_PRIVATE. Not sure why. And now I'm getting complaints that Titanium Backup doesn't back up the data for my app, since it seems to only do the /files folder? Sigh...

Comment: I'm using getDir with WORLD_WRITEABLE | WORLD_READABLE permissions. the i use `new FileInputStream(file);` to read it but i got permission denied exception. Can you please help?